# Can't map JSON data to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently trying to call an API and map an attribute to my model. e.g. image_src string from the JSON response to image string in my model. But right now It's getting the error '**no implicit conversion of String into Integer**'.

**Feed.rb**

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://extraction.import.io/query/runtime'
  has_many :entries

  # GET /feeds
  # GET /feeds.json

  def fetch_data

    response = self.class.get("/2365205f-8502-439e-a6d2-73988cfa03f1?&url=http%3A%2F%2F%2F")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["extractorData"]

    @elements.map do |image_info|
      self.entries.create(image: image_info['url'])
    end

  end
end
```

**Entry.rb**

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feed
end
```

**HTML**

```
<% @feed.entries.each do |image| %>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <%= image_tag(image) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "extractorData": {
    "url": "http://linxspiration.com/",
    "resourceId": "e26012fd5f25602c1c4e0945a7507e1f",
    "data": [
      {
        "group": [
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/0a38dd25a41e0702940c084b60bee860/tumblr_o5c0tyGhOP1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142509606341"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://36.media.tumblr.com/276def9e46bdfb9efee7f7d4e4444195/tumblr_o5c0szx4F21qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142506402604"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/4953cdecc24389d94844dfb88c819d8c/tumblr_o055uh8b7h1uhpqwfo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142503176501/linxsupply-discipline-gets-shit-done-buy-this"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://41.media.tumblr.com/353f10283fc3a0237262629b6a395c90/tumblr_o5aadrw6l31qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142499072059"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/889c65a662a1b690f299593e3581b947/tumblr_o57uysuSjF1tq9q5vo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142493659142/blazepress-sunrise-in-venice"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://45.media.tumblr.com/14c24e549a6559b48933f05ff40e3627/tumblr_o57vmsJ7gk1tq9q5vo1_400.gif",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142488060049/blazepress-i-lick-paw"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://36.media.tumblr.com/f184f397d14563c9e41136c5fe370016/tumblr_o59oo0pUy61qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142476686818"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/453b70fd4055952e907766a5942cc560/tumblr_o59ohsGHBo1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142470776914"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://41.media.tumblr.com/1de6c873de55ddb899f83441454ff5bb/tumblr_o59ohhnd0k1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142465333421"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/f71b3ee53f51a9679dc65096933f2b08/tumblr_o59of8kouq1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142456009994"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/b6aa0dc78619a6b9e09b232224c0bfb7/tumblr_o59oeu18Ly1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142452801623"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://41.media.tumblr.com/d1c5a23af31880d10fd89fc8a6a0b8e6/tumblr_o585z3mPuF1tq9q5vo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142449893982/blazepress-life"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://41.media.tumblr.com/03369de74399e12e1901b3751917c512/tumblr_o54gbfJlXx1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142445969058"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "image": [
              {
                "src": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/6543cbb31ea206a59cbdd1e865d63562/tumblr_o54mncUOEP1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg",
                "href": "http://linxspiration.com/post/142440337822"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "pageData": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "timestamp": 1460206655245
  }
}
```

Any help would be brilliant!

Comment: Are you trying to get the url http://linxspiration.com/ or img src's like http://40.media.tumblr.com/0a38dd25a41e0702940c084b60bee860/tumblr_o5c0tyGhOP1qkegsbo1_1280.jpg ?

Comment: I want to map each of the image->src to the  'image' field within the model

Comment: OK, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = self.class.get("/2365205f-8502-439e-a6d2-73988cfa03f1?&url=http%3A%2F%2F%2F")
puts response.parsed_response
```

Shows that the auth is failing:

```
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.9.7.3</center>
</body>
</html>


def fetch_data
  ...
  @elements = response.parsed_response["extractorData"]

  # To access the image src's:
  image_srcs = @elements['data'].first['group'].map{ | z | z['image'].first['src']}

  image_srcs.each do |src|
    self.entries.create(image: src)
  end
end
```

Comment: Auth is failing as I've removed my API key from the request ;). Would you be able to include the answer within the original model? Where would I put your additions? Thanks for answering

Comment: OK, that's good that you removed API key. Regarding "Would you be able to include the answer within the original model?", it is within the original model. I have updated the answer.